# Conditional trivariate probability mass function

Tags: probability, statistics

Below is a trivariate probability mass function, $P(X, Y, Z)$.

$$
\quad X
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
Z\quad Y & 10 & 20 & 30 \\
\hline
0\quad 1 & 0.04 & 0.24 & 0.12 \\
\quad -1 & 0.01 & 0.06 & 0.03 \\
1\quad 1 & 0.04 & 0.24 & 0.12 \\
\quad -1 & 0.01 & 0.06 & 0.03 \\
\end{array}
$$

Now i have been asked to find

$P(X|Y,Z)$

I know $P(Y)$ means marginal distribution of $Y$ and it is found by $\sum_{x,z}P(X, Y, Z)=P(Y)$

$$
Y
$$

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
1 & -1 \\
\hline
0.8 & 0.2 \\
\end{array}
$$

So $P(X|Y,Z)=$
$$\quad\quad X$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
Z\quad Y & 10 & 20 & 30 \\
\hline
0\quad 1 & \frac{0.04}{0.8}=0.05 & \frac{0.24}{0.8}=0.3 & \frac{0.12}{0.8}=0.15 \\
\quad -1 & \frac{0.01}{0.2}=0.05 & \frac{0.06}{0.2}=0.3 & \frac{0.03}{0.2}=0.15 \\
1\quad 1 & \frac{0.04}{0.8}=0.05 & \frac{0.24}{0.8}=0.3 & \frac{0.12}{0.8}=0.15 \\
\quad -1 & \frac{0.01}{0.2}=0.05 & \frac{0.06}{0.2}=0.3 & \frac{0.03}{0.2}=0.15 \\
\end{array}
$$

But

$P(X|Y,Z)=$
$$\quad\quad X$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr|c}
Z\quad Y & 10 & 20 & 30 \\
\hline
0\quad 1 & \frac{0.04}{0.8}=0.05 & \frac{0.24}{0.8}=0.3 & \frac{0.12}{0.8}=0.15 & 0.5 \\
\quad -1 & \frac{0.01}{0.2}=0.05 & \frac{0.06}{0.2}=0.3 & \frac{0.03}{0.2}=0.15 & 0.5\\
1\quad 1 & \frac{0.04}{0.8}=0.05 & \frac{0.24}{0.8}=0.3 & \frac{0.12}{0.8}=0.15 & 0.5\\
\quad -1 & \frac{0.01}{0.2}=0.05 & \frac{0.06}{0.2}=0.3 & \frac{0.03}{0.2}=0.15 & 0.5\\
\hline
 & 0.2 & 1.2 & 0.6 & \color{red}2
\end{array}
$$

*But mustn't it be $\color{red}1$?*

Where is the mistake?

Comment: you are calculating the marginal $P(Y)$, but you are supposed to calculate $P(Y,Z)=\sum_{x}P(X,Y,Z)$. Then you can calculate $P(X|Y,Z)=P(X,Y,Z)/P(Y,Z)$ and you will get the correct result.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Thank you.Could you please tell me is that the assumption ,for a trivariate pmf ,probability of one variable can be calculated given the other two variables?

Comment: the formula I've written gives exactly what you want to calculate and here no assumption is used.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay why is the conditional distribution of $P(X,Z|Y)$  not equal to $1$?

Comment: Do you want to mean $\sum_{x,z}P(X,Z|Y=y)$? This should be equal to 1 for all $y$ in the range of $Y$. Try to calculate some to get a better feel.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Practically $\sum_{x,z}P(X,Z|Y=y)$ is not equal to $1$. But why not , how can i compare it with real life example that is my headache, though i also don't know why $\sum_{x}P(X|Y,Z)$ always equal to $1$?

Comment: I think you are making some mistake in your calculations. Do you know that the conditional probability is also a probability measure and that's why all the axioms of probability are applicable to them? The fact that $\sum_{x,z}P(X,Z|Y=y)=1$ follows from that.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay yes,you are right.I have done mistake in calculation. Now it is clear to me from your 3 & 4 number comments. Thank you very much.

Comment: Very Welcome! @harry